# Module based styling in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I have an angular app with two modules in it. One is for public website and the other is for admin panel. For two modules, I have two layouts, and I have two seperate css files. Public website uses bootstrap and admin panel uses some angular theme. When I import both of css files in **angular.json**, my public website being effected by theme's css, and admin panel being effected by bootstrap either. I don't want it. Have can I import those css files module/layout based, and not globally?

**PS:** When I import them globally in **angular.json** and disable them in layout components' **ngOnInit** like `document.styleSheets[1].disabled = true;`, it causes problems. Like, after I log in and redirected to admin panel, panel opens with zero styles and I have to press F5 to refresh it. Likewise, when I log out and redirect to public website, it happens again and I have to press F5.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way for it.

I am importing target css files in layout components' scss files. That way, they are not effecting each other.

Comment: But, there is a new problem now. For ex:

Opening public site, works good. Logging in and redirecting to admin panel, works good. When I log out and redirect to public website, public website being effected by admin panel's css for couple seconds, then loads self css file.

Is there any way to prevent it?